# FileProvider from getFilesDir()

Tags: android, xml, file, android-context, android-fileprovider

What is the corresponding XML for Context.getFilesDir()?

My current XML:

```
<paths xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <files-path name="internal" path="." />
</paths>
```

File creation:

```
File video = new File(getFilesDir(), "movie.mp4");
videoUri = FileProvider.getUriForFile(this, "my.package.name.provider", video);
```

Comment: "stuff". Change to "internal".

Comment: What does "." in path mean?

Comment: @Rohit It represents the current working directory.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

That *is* the XML for serving files from `getFilesDir()` through `FileProvider`.

Comment: I get "Unable to open content" when I try to play video from that directory, but if I define File on Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() before MediaStore.ACTION_VIDEO_CAPTURE, video plays fine. Can you spot the problem? My app structure is: film a video using system intent and play it in VideoView.

Comment: @jelic98: Please provide a [mcve] demonstrating how you are using `FileProvider`. Specifically, are you adding `FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION` to the `Intent`?

Comment: I have managed to find the problem why VideoView is not playing desired video. Here is the new question: https://pastebin.com/uE72Jqd2 . Thanks for your help!

Comment: where is the XML ?

Comment: @Ivan: The XML is in the question.

Answer (score 0):

XML should be:

```
 <files-path
        name="avatar_image"
        path="camera" />
```

More info [here](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/core/content/FileProvider)